# Phonegap Cordova 2.2.0 & Android back button

Tags: android, cordova

I am having problem with Android's back button in my phonegap application.

Each time i press back it closes the whole application. Below is the codes that I have written. I refered to Phonegap API documentation for 2.2.0 here : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton

In the JS file:

```
function onLoad() {        
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);    
}   

function onDeviceReady() 
{              
   document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);    
}    

function onBackKeyDown() {      
   alert("back button"); 
}
```

HTML File:

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
```

All of the other functions are working except for the android physical back button. When I press back, it does not prompt me with an alert of "back button" but it just exits the whole application.

What am I doing wrong or did I miss something out?

Thank you.

Regards,

Amanda

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that the onDeciveryReady() is invoked? Try adding a console.log(""); and check in logcat that you actually get to the onDeviceReady.

I had no problem overriding the back button with your example.

Make sure your javascript file import is correct and that you are using the **cordova.js file for Android and not some other platform.**

As a side note, overriding certain buttons, like the Back button may be confusing for the user, if you plan to add some sort of "Exit Confirm?" dialog that should be fine but making it to something completely different than what is usually does is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

```
function onLoad() {        
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);    
}   

function onDeviceReady() 
{              
   document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.stopPropagation(); // ev is event
   }, false);    
}
```